# Loop through an array and remove matching patterns using grep

Tags: bash, shell

I have an array

```bash
array=("Tom" "Mango" "Boy")
```

and a file with the contents

```
Tom
Mango
Jam
Boy
Girl
Dog
Cat
```

I want to remove matching elements from the array and write them to a file.

I tried using a `for` loop

```bash
for t in ${array[@]}; do grep -v "$t" "file.txt" >> "file.txt.tmp";done
```

However this doesn't work as expected. It takes an argument each time and writes the excluded contents thus producing repetitions:

```
Mango
Jam
Boy
Girl
Dog
Cat
Tom
Jam
Boy
Girl
Dog
Cat
Tom
Mango
Jam
Girl
Dog
Cat
```

I want to produce the `file.txt.tmp` with all matching elements removed at one go ie. I want

```
Jam
Girl
Dog
Cat
```

Is there a way to do this with `for` loop and `grep`. I know I can use multiple patterns in `grep` seperated by `|` but I'm not sure how to use that *and* loop over the array elements.

Unfortunately `sed` won't work for me because I'm trying to remove the entire line containing part of a pattern ie. if there is a line

`Tom speaks` and the input pattern is `Tom`, I want to remove that entire line. `grep -v` seems the easiest way to do that.

Comment: Learn to take apart your looping statements etc to see that the inner parts work as required before continuing. If you would do `grep -v Mango file.txt` you would see right way where a major problem is (-;! ..... But then look at what `grep -v 'Tom|Mango' file.txt` can do.  ... Good luck.

Comment: Do you **have** to do this in bash? In zsh, you could simply do a `grep -v ${(j.|.)array} file.txt`.

Answer (score 3):

> I know I can use multiple patterns in grep seperated by | but I'm not sure how to use that and loop over the array elements.

You could format the array using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) and `IFS`, something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=("Tom" "Mango" "Boy")
pattern=$(IFS='|'; printf '%s' "${array[*]}")

grep -Ev "$pattern" file.txt
```

---

Output

```
Jam
Girl
Dog
Cat
```

---

check the value of the variable `pattern`,

```
declare -p pattern
```

---

Output

```
declare -- pattern="Tom|Mango|Boy"
```

---

Or just,

```
array=("Tom" "Mango" "Boy")

grep -Fxv "$(printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}")" file.txt
```

---

- See [How can I get all lines that are: in both of two files set intersection) or in only one of two files (set subtraction)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036)

Answer (score 2):

You *could* write them to a file.

```
$: printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" > patfile
$: grep -vf patfile fullfile
Jam
Girl
Dog
Cat
```

[Jetchisel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75894488/8656552) solution is probably better unless your list is big enough to strain your system or your configured limits, such as command line length, or an argument limit.

Neither of these is very likely these days, but maybe you're on an old system, or your sysadmin is overly Draconian. If that happens, you might have to use a file, and use a `for` loop instead of `printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}"`.

Most of your issue is from executing `grep` multiple times. Every time you run it (with all the time and overhead that will really add up on any bigger task) you are pulling every line that doesn't match *this* argument, which is why you get repeat values. You have to consolidate your exclusions, either into one pattern, or one file, so you can do it in one pass.